# Clearing the cache of a specific domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing an extension for Chrome and I want to programatically delete cache for a specific site (ex: www.randomdomain.com).

I'm aware of Chrome's [browsingData api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) and it's removeCache() and removeAppcache() functions. Is there a way to apply them to a specifc domain?

Comment: Judging by [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730202/access-google-chromes-cache) I would imagine that an extension has no insight into what is/isn't cached. Thus an extension cannot remove particular cache entries. I don't _know_ this, but that would be my best guess.

Comment: @Whymarrh Accessing and deleting cache items are different. The documentation linked by the OP clearly shows that Chrome extensions can delete items from the cache.

Comment: @RobW I was referring to _particular_ cache entries (e.g. by origin).

Comment: @Haque1 Did you succed with this? Seems like there was some progress last year in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `chrome.browsingData` API methods cannot be restricted to a certain domain. You can star [crbug.com/113621](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113621) and [crbug.com/113194](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113194) to get notified when it becomes possible.

(and there is no other API to control HTTP cache behavior per domain)